# How to display images within a drop down box instead of text

Tags: drop-down-menu

Are there any ways to show images instead of text within a drop down box (using the  tag)?

Thanks in advance,
Monte

Comment: Please please please tell us what Operating System, Windowing toolkit and Programming language you are using.  Or is this HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a images in select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with normal drop down boxes in HTML. You might be able to build something like a drop down box with JQuery or something similar, but there isn't anything to do this in normal HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optgroup tag inside of your selection tag. These are allowed to be styled and have a background image. Style it via css and put one option per group.

[w3c optgroup description](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're tagging about a dropdown box for a web browser. If that assumption is true, and if you're willing to use Javascript, then you could use something like the [Javascript Custom Dropdown v2.1](http://marghoobsuleman.com/blogs/jquery-image-dropdown) by Marghoob Suleman.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an ASP.NET server-side control (using AJAX) that has a checkbox list in what appears to be a dropdown, so I can tell you -- it CAN be done. Two panels, one which looks like a dropdown and shows the other when you click it. Put the payload in the other panel.

That get you started?