# changing paypal dropdown list into clickable images

Tags: html, css, forms, paypal

the dropdown is used in my paypal button:

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Type">Type of sauce <br />
<select name="os0">
<option value="Select a type">-- Select a type --</option>
<option value="Red">Red sauce</option>
<option value="Green">Green sauce</option>
</select> <br />
```

Can I change this dropdown to images. So the user selects the image rather than selecting a value from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do it in JQuery;

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

**BUT** I am not sure how it would affect PayPal so do a trial run in PayPals sandbox mode first.

You can try adding a background image in CSS but I believe that is rather limited in cross browser acceptability.

See here for other info:
 [putting images with options in a dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list)