# HTML- add html content in select tag options

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [putting images with options in a dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list)

Is it possible to have a dropDown list `<select>` with html options, some thing like a country selector with flag image inside each options. (please notice: without jquery UI)

Comment: no buddy you can't without it

Comment: @AspiringAqib Ahuh !are you sure ?

Comment: yeah i am! :P well, you can with js or jquery, not a select tag but another solution

Comment: `select`s are somewhat different from regular markup. Using plain `select`s without shimming a fancier overlay on top might work in some browsers, but it won't be consistent. Some browsers *lock down* what you can do with a `select` style-wise. I don't know why.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thank you very much , i found a solution in some Questions ! it seems that is good for me.thanks again.(`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list`)

Comment: The thing with the flag, I saw a really well-done framework just a couple days ago that I thought I bookmarked, that had that exact custom `select`. Little country flags to the left of the name. I can't seem to find it now, though.

Comment: @JaredFarrish ah yeah ! i'm trying to create a new one !

Comment: [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) looks a lot like the demos I saw, but it must have been another library like it. I know you said no jQUery, but those are some nice looking list selectors.

Comment: select2 is the new chosen, it's worth using in my opinion. It doesn't use jQuery UI thankfully, but does use jQuery.

Comment: @RichBradshaw - Yep, that *was* what I was looking for. Here's the one like described above: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/#templating