# dropdown list - show image options to select

Tags: asp-classic, html-select

I'd be greatful if you can help.

I would like to have a drop downlist that can have a view list of images rather than text content.

many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [putting images with options in a dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list)

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor question as you dont give much detail, however if you're working in [classic-asp](/questions/tagged/classic-asp) you can easily include [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) (client-side javascript library) and make use of the many plugins that offer this functionality, for example, one of the better ones (only in my opinion of course): http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo - note the examples - very easy to use, example:

[image]