# MVC Razor Dropdownlist with Image and label?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was wondering is there a way to list image and label using @Html.DropDownListFor helper in MVC razor?
Something like this:

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [dotnetspeaks.com](http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/ArticleImages/DropDownList%20with%20images.png))</sub>

Comment: Not with the standard helper as it only renders a specific set of HTML. Have a look at [**jquery image dropdown**](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) that might help.

Comment: Regardless of MVC this is going to be a HTML issue. Possible duplicate of SO issue [**putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list) then ?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing like this built into MVC, but I'm sure there are many 3rd-party components. I personally use [dijit](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/index.html) for this kind of thing, but since you have JQuery as one of your tags, you could probably use the [Menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/) from [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Answer (score 2):

`DropDownListFor` renders a `<select>`. This HTML element does not support an image in the list. you will need to use a JavaScript library to get this effect. several of the libraries use a `<select>` as the basis (they hide the select but get values form it.) there are dozens of select replacement libraries.

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://fairwaytech.com/2012/08/adding-images-select-lists-mvc3/), this will help you creating drop down list with images.

Answer (score -2):

look [here](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown). It is jquery, it is easy to implement with a few lines

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Scripts/msdropdown/dd.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/msdropdown/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/msdropdown/js/jquery.dd.js"></script>

    <div>
        <select name="webmenu" id="webmenu">
            <option value="calendar" title="~/Content/Images/arrow.png">Calendar</option>
            <option value="shopping_cart" title="~/Content/Images/SendtoFriend.jpg">Shopping Cart</option>
            <option value="cd" title="~/Content/Images/facebook.png">CD</option>
            <option value="email" title="~/Content/Images/Email.png">Email</option>
            <option value="faq" title="~/Content/Images/VotePositive.png">FAQ</option>
            <option value="games" title="~/Content/Images/VoteNegative.png">Games</option>
        </select>  
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#webmenu").msDropDown();
        });
   </script>
```

In order to work. I have to changed a Little.. I prefer to use `title` to show the image. It Works to me

Comment: how is this applicable to a @Html.DropDownListFor ?

Comment: you don´t, you should use
<select >
  @foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
<option value="@item.Name" title="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(item.ShowImgName)">@item.Name</option>
}
 </select>