# Need a js plugin with autocomplete and list items with icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have been browsing a lot for a javascript plugin or the workaround for dropdown combobox with autocomplete feature and list items with icons.

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/index.html

I found the above link on one of the solutions in stackoverflow [putting images with options in a dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list)

But this plugin does not contain autocomplete feature. I also need that the icon still displays in the selection after i select one of the list items. Anybody knows any workaround or any js plugin with these features?

Comment: You can use http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and build the list by editing the widget

Comment: ya,@grigno but that must be some coding.. I was looking for something more instant and ready..

Comment: try this on select2 http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/