# How to achieve drop down selection window in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I want to achieve a selection box in the drop down window.(I'm using something like

`<%= f.select(:season, options_for_select(['spring/fall', 'winter', 'summer'], 'spring/fall'))%>`

for the selection box for now)

In this window, I want to have many icons. The user can select one of these icons. And the selected icon will be saved in the database as one attribute of the object.

Can I do this without JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use the background-image property to set icons in a dropdown, but apparently it only works in Firefox

See this question for discussions of how to do it with JS [putting images with options in a dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list)