# How to add small thumbnails to `<option>` elements in a `<select>` list?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add small thumbnail images (20x20 pixels) to `<option>` elements in a `<select>` list but I'm unable to find a working solution.

I searched SO and Google and found the following example:

```
<select>
  <option style="background-image:url(/_assets/_img/thumbnail1.png)">Item 1</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(/_assets/_img/thumbnail2.png)">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

For some reason this doesn't load thumbnails. I made sure to test the paths and the thumbnails do exist (I did a `<img src="/_assets/_img/thumbnail1.png">` before the list to check that images get loaded.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Use jqueryui http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Despite the other answers here, you won't be able to do this reliably in all browsers. Each browser presents a `<select>` field completely differently. Your best bet is to fake a select field using normal HTML elements, and when it changes, update a hidden select field with javascript.

See this SO answer 
[putting images with options in a dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list)

Comment: There's a jQuery plugin that does it relatively simply http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

Comment: Good example. This has been done hundreds of times before, OP should use a plugin instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: but, i only want this one feature, so a plugin is major overkill

Comment: Some plugins might be "major overkill" but using a plugin isn't inherently overkill. In this case OP will likely be recreating all of the functionality of the HTML <select>, which will be complex if they intend to make it work "to spec." After adding the behavior and keyboard controls, a plugin may not feel like such overkill anymore.

Comment: ddSlick plugin doesn't look maintained (44 issues outstanding, no activity within a year) and I get overly large heights when I tried using it so it doesn't work for me.