# Add images with <option> in <select> dropdown list in *ngFor

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, html-select, angular-reactive-forms, ngfor

Im trying to add image in my dropdown using *ngFor but Im unable to show the image icon, but can show text, Any idea how to solve this ? this is what I had tried :

**html**

```
  <form [formGroup]="countryForm">
          <select formControlName="countryControl" (change)="optionSelected($event.value)">
          <option [value]="country" *ngFor="let country of countries"><img class="icon-custom" [src]="country.icon" [alt]="country.viewValue">{{country.viewValue}}</option></select>
  </form>
```

**ts**

```
      countries = [
        { value: 'xxx-0', viewValue: 'xxx (+xx)', code: 'xx', icon: '../../assets/svg/icon-cc-add-blue.svg' },
        { value: 'yyy-0', viewValue: 'yyy (+yy)', code: 'yy', icon: '../../assets/svg/icon-cc-add-blue.svg' }
];

  optionSelected(event) {
    this.selectedIcon = event.value.icon;
  }
```

I need to solve this using typesript/angular without using any jquery plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add small thumbnails to \`<option>\` elements in a \`<select>\` list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697386/how-to-add-small-thumbnails-to-option-elements-in-a-select-list)

Comment: im using  *ngFor, it does the difference

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment below by @hazifi. The option tag only supports text - [Link here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option). You could use a background-image but it would limit you in the positioning of other elements.

[How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

Probably the best solution also mentioned in the comments is using angular material:

[How to implement angular 7 drop-down with images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003063/how-to-implement-angular-7-drop-down-with-images)

Comment: What do you have in your angular.json defined as assets?
`"assets": [?]`

Comment: "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]  @nephi

Comment: @hafizi I think your svg is files might miss some info. I have tried in a sample project and had the same issue. Can you share the content of one of your svg's?

Comment: I dont think it svg.. it is because <option> does not support image, it only support text, if using angular material, it can be done like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003063/how-to-implement-angular-7-drop-down-with-images , but im using bulma framework instead of angular material,

Comment: @hazifi I have updated my answer to reflect your findings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198160/discussion-between-nephi-and-hafizi).

Comment: background-image is deprecated by firefox..and also I dont want to use angular material,