# select images, which represent integer?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dropdown

A user chooses a ranking `<%= f.select :ranking, Challenge::EMOTICONS %>`. `ranking: integer`.

```
EMOTICONS = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png']
```

How can I show the user the emoticon images in place of the integers these emoticons represent in a dropdown menu?

```
4 = :] = 4.png # Smilely face strings are an example. I have better quality emoticon images I'd like to use
3 = :) = 3.png
2 = :( = 2.png
1 = :[ = 1.png
```

[image]

Comment: You might be stuck using a plugin like [ddSlick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick). Regular HTML `<select>` options don't allow images. You might be able to use a custom font for simple symbols.

Comment: Which UI (CSS and Javascript) framework(s) are you using or planning to use.  Most of them have a solution or allow plugin solutions that give you styled select options.  Sadly, the standard HTML set does not, and it is reasonably difficult to roll your own.

Comment: Do you want to show an actual image on the dropdown or just the emoticon representation of that integer?

Comment: Yea @tadman. That might be a good option. Otherwise for now I'm going to try to just show all four emoticons. Increase the opacity for nonactive ones and then when user hovers or clicks on one then remove transparency. Here is a new question to help me toward that goal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038221/how-to-pass-attribute-data-by-clicking-on-image

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list) may help answer your question, or at least shed light on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the filenames in your views ("1.png"), why not use the emoticon strings i.e. `EMOTICONS = [':)', ':(', ':|', ':@']`

Then on the server, you could use a `case` statement on the param to find the matching filename.