# How to pass attribute data by clicking on image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to pass attribute data by clicking on an image:

```
# Something like this I would imagine
<%= f.select '1.png', ranking: 1 %>
# or
<%= f.image_tag '1.png', ranking: 1 %>
```

**Attempts Based Upon @Tadman**

1

```
  <%= f.hidden_field(:ranking, id: 'ranking') %>
  <%= image_tag('1.png', data: { rank: 1 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('2.png', data: { rank: 2 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('3.png', data: { rank: 3 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('4.png', data: { rank: 4 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
```

2

```
  <%= f.hidden_field(:ranking, id: 'image_ranking') %>
  <%= image_tag('1.png', data: { image_ranking: 1 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('2.png', data: { image_ranking: 2 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('3.png', data: { image_ranking: 3 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('4.png', data: { image_ranking: 4 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
```

3

```
  <%= f.hidden_field(:image_ranking, id: 'image_ranking') %>
  <%= image_tag('1.png', data: { ranking: 1 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('2.png', data: { ranking: 2 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('3.png', data: { ranking: 3 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
  <%= image_tag('4.png', data: { ranking: 4 }, class: 'image-clicker') %>
```

Comment: Does [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list) answer your question?

Comment: It sheds light on the previous question I asked @MichaelGaskill, but not for this question. This question isn't about dropdown. I just want it where if a user clicks on an image, then that image will pass `ranking: 1` upon the user clicking submit on the _form. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oops, sorry, I posted it in the wrong one.  I was looking a the other and clicked through to this one before I added the link.  I'll add it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you do this with the unobtrusive JavaScript available in Rails:

```
<%= f.hidden_field(:image_ident, id: 'image_ident') %>
<%= image_tag('1.png', data: { ident: 1 }, class: 'img-clicker') %>
```

Then you can trigger it with jQuery:

```
$('.img-clicker').click(function() {
  $('#image_ident').val($(this).data('ident'));
});
```

Idea here is you can have a hidden field to capture your selection and each image when clicked transfers its `data` value over. You can even add class information to make the selected image look different afterwards, up to you.

Comment: I just changed `ident` with `ranking` wherever it appeared, but I keep getting the error `undefined method image_ranking`

Comment: If your field is `ranking`, then `hidden_field(:ranking, ...)` should do it.

Comment: Updated question with attempts. `:ranking` is the field. Am I suppose to add something to the controller with `hidden_field`. And it is `hidden_field right`? Not `hidden_field_tag`

Comment: `hidden_field_tag` is for an arbitrary field not bound to anything, `f.hidden_field` is intrinsically populated with whatever value it can extract from the form's associated model.

Comment: I've tried probably 25 different versions of your answer. And then realized I forgot to add `:ranking` to params :/ Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You mentioned "You can even add class information to make the selected image look different afterwards" I added class information to `img-clicker` but that changes the way it looks preselected. How do I change the way it looks once it is selected?

Comment: By adding something like `$(this).addClass('clicked')` or whatever your "clicked" style is. You may need to `$('.clicked').removeClass('clicked')` to de-click all the others that might have been previously clicked.

Comment: Thanks! That got me on track. This was how I fully implemented it to work if you're curious: `<script>
  $('.image-clicker').click(function() {
    $('#ranking').val($(this).data('ranking'));
    $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked')
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
  });
</script>`