# Why does it not appear image in option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a thumbnail for my autocomplete option but I couldn't see my image on option no matter I use css.what's wrong with my code or how can it be happen using image on option ? I'm talking about for all option different image and I don't want to use style background because it work's only firefox

```css
select {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

option {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<select>
<option>Option 1 <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/web-development-5/500/coffee-break-html-code-64.png"></option>
<option>Option 2 <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/web-development-5/500/checked-www-domain-window-64.png"></option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a images in select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [putting images with options in a dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do it in this way, i tried in one of my project while taking my Bachelor of Science in Software Engineering at the university of Dodoma.

```
<select>
  <option style="background-image:url(option1.png);">option 1</option>

  <option style="background-image:url(option2.png);">option 2</option>

</select>
```

or for better results do it as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="selection">
  <option>option 1</option>

  <option>option 2</option>

</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
select#selection option[value="option 1"] { background-image:url(option1.png); }


select#selection option[value="option 2"] { background-image:url(option2.png); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, only in firefox is possible to add a background-image on select:

```
<select>
  <option style="background-image: url(images/1.jpg)">Option1 </option>
  <option style="background-image: url(images/2.jpg)">Option2 </option>
</select>
```