# Bootstrap Form input list with image

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is There A way i can Display Images in a bootstrap list. i have tried but cant seam to get it to work?

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo '
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">To:</label>
  <select class="form-control border-radius" id="sel1">  

    ';
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option><img src="assets/img/Team Members/'.$row["Profile_Picture"].'"></option>';
    }
    echo '
</select>
</div>


    ';
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: You can use css, have you tried the answer I provided?

Answer (score 0):

Use css instead

```
echo "<option value='value' style='background-image:url(assets/img/Team Members/'.$row['Profile_Picture'].');'>Profile Name</option>'
```

You can take a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list).