# How to attach an image with dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add an image next to the text in a dropdownlist control but it doesn't work for me. Where is the problem?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpRoomSetup" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem>Select a style</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem  style="background-image:url(U.GIF);">U 
      style</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem  style="background-
     image:url(Classroom.GIF);">Small rectangular table/chairs)
    </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in html.
Hope it answers your question.

```html
<select>
    <option value="volvo" style="background-image:url(images/volvo.png);">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab"  style="background-image:url(images/saab.png);">Saab</option>
    <option value="honda" style="background-image:url(images/honda.png);">Honda</option>
    <option value="audi"  style="background-image:url(images/audi.png);">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Check out this link if you need it for a different scenario
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list)