# Dropdown for currency of countries with flag

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can someone help us to create like this dropdown,
I've already search this kind but what I found is dropdown for countries with flag only. thanks

[click this to view my sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Adh0.png)

[image: this is the sample image]

Please Help us

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Show your work so far

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Putting images with options in a dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list)

Answer (score 0):

How about...

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/75/50/abstract/">
      0123 4567 8912 3456
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-header">Member name (you)</li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" title="Select this card"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/75/50/abstract/">0123 4567 8912 3456</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" title="Select this card"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/75/50/abstract/">0123 4567 8912 3456</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-header">Member name</li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" title="Select this card"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/75/50/abstract/">0123 4567 8912 3456</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body { padding: 40px; }
.dropdown-toggle, .dropdown-menu { width: 300px }
.btn-group img { margin-right: 10px }
.dropdown-toggle { padding-right: 50px }
.dropdown-toggle .glyphicon { margin-left: 20px; margin-right: -40px }
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover { background: #f1f9fd } /* $search-blue */
.dropdown-header { background: #ccc; font-size: 14px; font-weight: 700; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px }
```

[Image in dropdown demo](https://codepen.io/fsanggang/pen/ZOepzE)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you need simple drop down html  you can find the code in this [link](https://visibleranking.com/html-list-of-currencies-in-the-world.php).

however if you need advanced js, css you can find it in this [link](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=22000)

Comment: answering with a link is not a good answer because link with rot and the answer with have no use for future readers