# show icon first select option

Tags: html, css

i have a standard select html attribute and what i want to do is add an icon to the selected option list basically it shows the user that this select has download options here's my code.

```
 <select>
    <option style="background-image: url('https://s17.postimg.cc/kc1y6xwlb/download.png')"></option>
    <option>PDF</option>
    <option>CSV</option>
 </select>
```

this is what i am trying to achieve!

[image: source]

i have tried a couple of solutions but none seems to be working for my issue, any help?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovr3qo24/)

Comment: `https://postimg.cc/image/voejoq5a3/` does not return an image, but an HTML document - duh! And on whether this is possible to begin with, I think you should do some more/proper research ...

Comment: my apologies i have edited the fiddle and code please refresh

Comment: This might help. http://taylor.fausak.me/2012/03/15/dropdown-menu-in-twitter-bootstraps-collapsed-navbar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we cannot style an `option` element using only CSS.

But, we can do it on the `select`!
Is my snippet the kind of thing you are trying to achieve?

```css
select {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 24px;
  background-image: url('https://s17.postimg.cc/kc1y6xwlb/download.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 8px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option hidden>…</option>
  <option>PDF</option>
  <option>CSV</option>
</select>
```

You might be interested in this topic: [Putting images with options in a dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/putting-images-with-options-in-a-dropdown-list)

I hope it helps.

Comment: very close please see the edited question for the image i placed!

Comment: yes i have tried the above answer already the problem is firefox doesnt support it!

Comment: @uneebmeer Yes, it doesn't support it anymore. :) In my snippet, I've put the download image in that position so it continues to fit when selecting an option. I don't know how to do better !

Comment: the problem in your solution is if i add a background image to the select the next option text comes along with it whereas i want it to show only the download icon

Comment: @uneebmeer What if we don't put any text in the option?

Comment: the it display blank option which looks bad!

Comment: yes i have and idea i dsiplayed none the empty option and it worked! ty so much for your help!