# How to place images in the options of a dropdown list?

Tags: html, model-view-controller

I want to show a dropdown list with cities and flags. Like this (sorry example made in Excel)...

[image]

I tried this. But this code doesn't work.

```
<select id="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
@foreach (var city in Model.City)
{
    <option value="@(city.Id)">@(city.Name) [<img src="~/images/'@(city.Country.CountryIsoCode3)'.png/" width="16" height="16">]</option>
}
</select>
```

Can someone help me?

**I see something with "`<select class="selectpicker">`" by using Bootstrap. Which js, css files do I need exactly?  I think that this could be the solution...**

Comment: I can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941004/

Comment: How is it not working. Can you describe how is your code failing? Also, what is your tech stack? The code you have is not pure HTML, you use a template engine. Please specify what you are using and how is your current try failing.

Comment: If you create a snippet and add it to your question, that would also be helpful.

Comment: I use a model for data. And there is code like C#/Razor.

Comment: @user1531040 How is it failing? Do you get an error? What do you see in the browser? "Not working" is so vague that it's very difficult to understand the precise problem. This is why asked you to elaborate.

Comment: What would you see more. It starts with a @model. And there is a label within a div. And the image will found when write the code. (wwwroot\images\)

Comment: I see something with <select class="selectpicker"> by using Bootstrap. Which js, css files do I need exactly?  I think that that is the solution...

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using an emoji for this.

```
<select name="country">
  <option>GB </option>
  <option>FR </option>
  <option>DE </option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2mnzproa/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I see in your example no images.

Comment: It's true that on some older operating system and browsers this won't work. you can use this [website](http://caniemoji.com) as reference. In my opinion using an emoji and text is the graceful degradation way of doing this. Most users will have the optimal experience, and for users on older systems it's still useable.

Comment: It's resolved. With bootstrap (data-content).