# how to add image to dropdown using javascript in jsp

Tags: javascript, image, jsp, drop-down-menu

I am setting name of few countries List in Session Object. I need to populate a dropdown in my JSP using this List and also add the Flag Images before each country name in the select option dynamically.
The below code does not work:

```
    <select id="refSelect" onChange="refreshRefList();" name='refSelect'>
     <c:forEach var='flag' items="${sessionScope.flagList}">
      <option value="${flag}">
        <img src="./images/${flag}.PNG"/> <c:out value="${flag}" />
      </option>
     </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

I also tried to achieve this using CSS using below link but it failed for session List and only works in Firefox browser:

- [How to add a images in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Seems like normal default Dropdown control does not support images. Can anyone help me to achieve this using Javascript/CSS/Custom taglib. I don't want to use jQuery in my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a textbox,

create a

```
<ul id="country_dropdown"><li><img src="urimage.png"/>Country</li>...</ul>
```

on focus on the textbox, show country_dropdown, on blur or on click on li hide the ul.

no jquery needed to achieve that.

also the use div instead of textbox and maintain the value as hidden.

Comment: hi @sk08. Thanks for you suggestion. I would really appreciate if you could show this with some actualy code example or give reference to any link where i can get reference from. Also will the above method work for a List of countries stored in Session Object or will it only work for some hard-coded countries names?

Answer (score 0):

You may try **[JavaScript image combobox](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @blasteralfred , thank for your link, but i have already visited it before. This link has mentioned it has dependency on jQuery. I don't want to use jQuery. Thanks.