# Add a color box in select box

Tags: css

I have a problem. I have a drop down of colors.

For example

```
<select>
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
</select>
```

I want to add a colored box before the name of the color.

I can't find a solution for this.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: That will not be possible with only CSS and a `select` element. You will have to implement some kind of custom dropdown-list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found a way to easily add color boxes or images directly to Select boxes, but it's relatively simple to do this by replacing Select elements with Definition List (DL) elements. There's an excellent tutorial showing you how to do this [here](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx)

I created a jsfiddle with color boxes http://jsfiddle.net/NjaEL/ *(just change the path for the arrow icon so that an arrow is displayed in the container)*.

The basic code is:

HTML

```
<dl class="dropdown">
<dt ><a href="#"><span>Color</span></a></dt>
<dd>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="color" style="background-color:Red"></span>Red<span class="value">Red</span></a></li>
     ...       
     </ul>
</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown dd, .dropdown dt, .dropdown ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; } .dropdown dd { position:relative; } .dropdown dt a {background:#ffffff url(images/arrow1.png) no-repeat scroll 97.5% center ; display:block; padding-right:20px;width:70px; border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;} .dropdown dt a:hover { color:#212121; border: 1px solid #999999;} .dropdown a, .dropdown a:visited { color:#555555; text-decoration:none; outline:none;} .dropdown a:hover { color:#212121;} .dropdown dd ul { background:#ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0; border:1px solid #d3d3d3; color:#555555; display:none; left:0px; padding:5px 0px; position:absolute; top:0px; width:90px; list-style:none;} .dropdown dd ul li a { padding:5px; display:block;} .dropdown span.value { display:none;} .dropdown .color { border: 1px solid silver; vertical-align:middle; margin-right:5px; min-width: 10px;}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
});
$(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
    $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
});
function getSelectedValue(id) {
    return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});
});
```

Comment: @DanBarzilay: Thanks :-D Any chance that you know how to modify the script so that the color box formatting is applied to selected items?

Comment: You're awesome!!! I love how in trying to help someone else I also got an answer that I needed :-D

Comment: It's my pleasure to be able to 'pay it forward' :-D

Comment: but how to get the value of selected option?

Comment: It looks like it works almost fine. But when I click on the dropdown the page scrolls up. Just add some text before the dropdown to see it: http://jsfiddle.net/ce4wntpm/

Answer (score 0):

With CSS only it wouldn't work in all browsers - read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2966006/1361042

and your colored box should be an image.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying how to do it using images? I know how to do it with menus (thanks to http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx :-) ), but it's a bit more challenging with select boxes than I would have expected

Comment: @ChayaCooper You can use ur menu design and JS code and add an hidden select elemnt and when the user clicks an item on the menu (which will act as a selct box) the JS will change the hidden select selected item.

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear :-) I was wondering how to do it using select boxes instead of menu items (which can be a bit more complicated to work with)

Comment: @ChayaCooper You don't need to get in that select boxes mess just use those menu and u'll be good to go ;)

Comment: Thanks :-) I've modified jankoatwarpspeed's post to use background colors instead of images (although I'm still trying to fix the script so that the colorbox formatting is applied to the DT container), and I'll share my code below to help @comebal know how to do it :-)