# Add a background color in selector

Tags: html, css

I wanted to put a small rectangle of green color in a selector. I tried a lot but could not find a solution.

```
<select>
    <option value="all_clicks"  selected="selected" class="greenRect">All clicks</option>
    <option value="search_camp">Search campaigns</option>
    <option value="search_links">Search links</option>
    <option value="none">None</option>
</select>
```

```
.greenRect{
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
    backround:#7db22b;
    border-radius:2px;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DVyQC/

Similar to shown in figure! Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not likely be able to do this with CSS. Select boxes are one of the least 'styleable' elements.

Here's a similar post: [How to add a images in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

This answer describes a CSS solution for Fx only.

Answer (score 1):

Well you won't be able to do that using the normal  tag, instead what you can do (and you also be able to make it look pretty) is to use a normal list `<ul><li>` and recreate the selector behavior

Answer (score 1):

in the option this type of approach can be possible but this can be done by jquery or javascript

check [this](http://apycom.com/) there are many dropdown

Answer (score 1):

You could use msDropdown and create different colored rectangle images to put on each option.
http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

This is certainly not as smooth as using CSS but it might work.