# select menu html value

Tags: php, html

How can I add html value for select menu options:

```
<select name="symbol">
  <option>select</option>
  <option value="<img src="start.jpg"">start</option>
  <option value="<img src="end.jpg"">end</option>
</select>
```

I want post value to show an image.

I read this : [How to add a images in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)
but I want send image value.

Comment: Do you mean when someone selects an option from the SELECT then an image will appear/change somewhere on the page?

Comment: no this form is post action
i want post html value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're handling the post with PHP or some similar server-side code, you should pass through only the reference to the image. Any tags can be output using the server-side code. For example:

```
<select name="symbol">
    <option>select</option>
    <option value="start.jpg">start</option>
    <option value="end.jpg">end</option>
</select>
```

And then handle this by doing something like:

```
echo '<img src="'.$_POST['symbol'].'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes instead of double qoutes inside value...

```
<select name="symbol">
  <option>select</option>
  <option value="<img src='b.jpg'>">start</option>
  <option value="<img src='a.jpg'>">end</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is reason of use : onchange="frm.submit();" ?

Comment: its a js script that automatically submit your form when you change option in the select list...

Comment: Using obtrusive event handlers is very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use single quote and close  tag. Try this,

```
<select name="symbol">
          <option>select</option>
          <option value="<img src='start.jpg'>">start</option>
          <option value="<img src='end.jpg'>">end</option>
</select>
```