# How to show images in <option> elements rendered by <h:selectOneMenu> tag

Tags: image, jsf, selectonemenu

Is it possible to show images in `<option>` elements rendered by `<h:selectOneMenu>` tag of JSF?

I use `<f:selectItems>` to generate the options that I get from the database. But the content I want to show in `<h:selectOneMenu>` is the image associated with each item.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to embed images within JSF's `<h:selectOneMenu>`/`<f:selectItem>`/`<f:selectItems>`, as there are no attributes designed for that purpose. Moreover, there is hardly a [cross-browser compatible solution for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2966006/1820286).

Though you could use a component library for that, like PrimeFaces. It has `<p:selectOneMenu>` component that basically wraps `<select>`/`<option>` with some HTML/jQuery magic, so that a 'substitute' is displayed onscreen. Example usage can be found in a [showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf). To recite it:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{autoCompleteBean.selectedPlayer2}" converter="player" var="p">  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
    <f:selectItems value="#{autoCompleteBean.players}" var="player" itemLabel="#{player.name}" itemValue="#{player}"/>  

    <p:column>  
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/barca/#{p.photo}" width="40" height="50"/>  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column>  
        #{p.name} - #{p.number}  
    </p:column>  
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Of course, you can load the images in a different manner.

Comment: Yes, i am using primefaces.. In this case, i have to implement a converter class, or primefaces do it for me?

Comment: That's not related to your question. The structure of `<p:selectOneMenu>` closely resembles that of `<h:selectOneMenu>`, but with some 'extras'. As for the converter, it is needed in case you'd like to map a string (the one from the selected option) to anything else, like your model class (like `Player` in PrimeFaces example). To repeat, in case it's needed in JSF it is as well needed in PrimeFaces.

Comment: Is it normal it is insanely slow ? When I say slow I mean like 1 MINUTE to load a page. Where the selectOneMenu has 250 elements and 250 images, images add up to 130 ko though so it isn't so high.