# Icon in option - Bootstrap + Font-awsome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, html-select

I am trying to embed an icon in an option from a select list. Using font-awesome icons, no icon is being displayed.

```
<select>
    <option><i class="icon-camera-retro"></i> Doesn't work in option!</option>
</select>
```

Can I use font-awesome to achieve what I need? Or do I have to scrap using font-awesome and do a manual CSS background for each option?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mmXh2/1/

Comment: I think there is more simple solutions, but you can have a look at this amazing jquery plugins: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html, the templating part can interest you.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list

Comment: @PSL I actually saw that before i posted thats why i mentioned 'a manual CSS background for each option' but I would prefer to use the font-awesome framework.

Answer (score 19):

You can use FontAwesome as a unicode font and insert your icons in a cross-platform way.  You just need to look up the unicode value for each icon

```
<select style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', Helvetica;">
    <option>&#xf083; Now I show the pretty camera!</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome, Safari and Opera (Mac) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PageLab/y49pd/)

Comment: I don't have a Mac but it should work there.  Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: On a Mac, it works only in Firefox. This is being tracked in [Github](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/996) also:

Comment: Firefox is still the best. That settles it.

Comment: Works in Chrome/windows 7 here. But get this: It also works in IE10, but only when showing the selected option, when the select is collapsed. The option list itself has no Icons... Quirky!

Answer (score 5):

You can cheat a little bit and put the class on the option:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmXh2/2/

```
<option class="icon-camera-retro"> Doesn't work in option!</option>
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I knocked it up in Firefox and it works there but not in Chrome. Ah well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i tried this in chrome originally and thought it didn't work, but would need a cross browser solution. I think i have to go for a simple background image

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Select2 (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) is a solution to putting icons in option tags. However, perhaps due to my lack of knowledge, I just couldn't make it work. In the end I resorted to using lists (I was also using Bootstrap)

```
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle category" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">All Categories <span class="caret pull-right"></span></a>
<ul id="category" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon"></i> Category A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon"></i> Category B</a></li>
    ..
</ul>
```

There is a drawback though, the id of the list has to be unique. So, if like me you had 5 different lists in one page, you have to declare (?) all of them in javascript making the codes chunky.

```
$(function(){
  $("#category li a").click(function(){
    $(".category").val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Hope that help shed some light.

Comment: recently found a way to put icons into <option> tags: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

Answer (score 0):

Use a plugin like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBW7y/)

```
<select id="icon_select" style="width: 150px;"><option value="fa-glass">&amp;#xf000; fa-glass</option>
  <option value="fa-music">&amp;#xf001; fa-music</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for icons working in Chrome has been given [on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21567956/1438561).

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SiamKreative/qCn6p/)

Code used:

```
function format(icon) {
    var originalOption = icon.element;
    return '<i class="fa ' + $(originalOption).data('icon') + '"></i> ' + icon.text;
}
$('.wpmse_select2').select2({
    width: "100%",
    formatResult: format
});
```