# Arrow-Down in React Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, html-select

i have a dropdown in react render else condition. i want to put the arrow down like fa-caret-down next to label selectValue. tried the font awesome icon it's not working.
Code Below:

```
    else {
          return (
            <select id="dropdown">
              <option label={t("selectValue")} />
            </select>
          )
    }
```

Any HeadsUp?

Comment: try using react-toolbox for better ui.are you using css or style loader because without appropriate loaders your classes like fa-caret-down wont be compiled

Comment: any code snippet?

Comment: else {
          return (
            <select id="dropdown">
              <option label={t("selectValue")} />
            </select>
    }

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525513/icon-in-option-bootstrap-font-awsome