# Styling option tag with text and text-icon

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

In my project I use something like Font Awesome. It's *Magic the Gathering* mana set and it works same as FA.

[image: image from my page]

My problem is: Yesterday I achieved to have icons inside option - through:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekb5o8L9/)

Actually my problem is text is writed with ugly text.

My idea is something like write `"&example; txet emos"`, `::first-letter`, and then flip it. Is `&example;` equal like 1 letter? If not then how?

Or other idea: change font for text in "my FA".

Comment: I realise that Christmas eve is never going to be an easy time to get help, but I'd suggest trying to quickly explain your problem to a friend/colleague, with a better grasp of English, in your native language and then have them assist in editing your question. I *think* you're wanting to use MtG mana fonts in your `<option>` elements? The answers to this question may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525513/icon-in-option-bootstrap-font-awsome

Comment: Look at snippets, i have already done this. My problem is, font of ManaIcon is ugly on text. And thanks for reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, solution is very easy. Change `style="font-family: 'FontAwesome';"` to `style="font-family: 'FontAwesome', 'yourfont (example: Arial)';"`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrt18n43/2/)