# No extension in select php?

Tags: php, select, echo

I have the following select but I dont want it to show .jpg can you guys help me 
and if I select a name option it has to echo the image file.

```
    <?php 

    $images = glob("smoelenboek/*.{jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);
    echo '<select name="image">';
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
    echo '<option>' . basename($image) . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<option>' . basename($image) . '</option>'

    ?>
```

Comment: Use `basename($image, '.jpg')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, use the second parameter to `basename()`:

```
echo '<option>' . basename($image, '.jpg') . '</option>';
```

Although, you will need to reconsider this method should you start to list files with other suffixes

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of [`basename`](http://www.php.net/basename) allows you to cut off the extension, if it is present:

```
echo basename('test.jpg', '.jpg'); // echoes test
```

note that while `basename` accepts a path as first parameter, it does not actually check the file system to validate the file, any string can thus be passed.

**edit**

For the additional question about displaying the images itself in the select: as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list) that is not really possible in a cross browser way.

You could use custom components for this like [the jQuery Selectable](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/)

Comment: I want it to echo the full image not only the name if that is possible

Comment: what do you mean "echo the full image"? display the image in the select?

Comment: A select does not allow you to display images inside it, you will have to use a custom component for this. see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Comment: hmm okey i will search for that and if i want it to show the image in an other div?

Comment: That's another question entirely, which I will not try to resolve in a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$images = glob("smoelenboek/*.{jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);
echo '<select name="image">';
foreach($images as $image)
{
echo '<option value="'.basename($image, '.jpg').'">' . basename($image) . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<?php 

        $images = glob("smoelenboek/*.{jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);
        echo '<select name="image">';
        foreach($images as $image)
        {
        echo '<option style="background: url('. $image . ') no-repeat; ">'. basename($image) . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
       echo '<option style="background: url('. $image . ') no-repeat;">'. basename($image) . '</option>';

        ?>
```