# Trying to echo an image source in a select option list

Tags: php, html

I have a php loop where I am trying to echo a HTML image source inside the select option tag, like this:

```
foreach($recs as $i){
    if($i->isscripted == 1){
      $is = "<img src='greencheck.gif'>"; 
    }else{
      $is = "<img src='redbang.gif'>"; 
    }

   echo "<option value=".$i->id.">".$is."  ".$i->fullname."</option>";
}
```

The image is not displaying in the select list.  I tested the image tag outside of the loop and it displays fine.

```
echo "<img src='greencheck.gif'>";
```

Comment: Um... because you can't put images inside `<option></option>` tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a images in select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do it using pure HTML, but there are a few workarounds:

1. **CSS Background (Works only in firefox):**

   ```
   <select>
       <option value="volvo" style="background-image:url(images/volvo.png);">Volvo</option>
       <option value="saab"  style="background-image:url(images/saab.png);">Saab</option>
       <option value="honda" style="background-image:url(images/honda.png);">Honda</option>
       <option value="audi"  style="background-image:url(images/audi.png);">Audi</option>
   </select>
   ```
2. **Using a jQuery Plugin**

   > #### [JavaScript Image Dropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)
   >
   > Are you tired with your old fashion dropdown? Try this new one. Image combo box. You can add an icon with each option. It works with your existing "select" element or you can create by JSON object.

   http://www.queness.com/resources/images/formplugin/22.gif

Comment: Great CSS workaround, thanks so much for the idea. This is for an internal customer where I can say, "only use FF"!

Comment: Ha ha @jamesTheProgrammer, that would be awesome! :)

Answer (score 1):

A nice solution from [vartec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60711/vartec)

You can try it and thanks to him

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2966006/2459296)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
foreach($recs as $i){
    if($i->isscripted == 1){
      $is = "greencheck.gif"; 
    }else{
      $is = "redbang.gif"; 
    }

   echo "<option value=".$i->id."  style='background-image:url(".$is."); background-repeat:no-repeat; padding-left:30px;'>".$i->fullname."</option>";
}
```

Comment: Salim, thanks so much, This worked like a charm.  Send me a bill!

Answer (score 0):

You cant have images inside `<option>`,it can take only textual options, you will need to get it out and maybe do some javascript or jquery to display the image somewhere else when you select an option. There are also Jquery pluggins that can do this as http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick