# Keep select options after refresh with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Have been working on a smaller project with php here and got lost. I'll explain in two parts.

**Part 1:** I have index.php and a getitem.php. Index contains a form with multiple select objects with no options (at start) with the exception of one. After selecting an item from the one with options available I make a query via getitem.php&[parameters_here]. The php then echoes options with values and texts.

This form then guides you to fill every field this way. These options are added on the go with object.innerhtml. Everything fine.

The problem kicks in when you hit the refresh button. Select items lose their options (with the exception of the one). How to keep these settings on refresh? Keeping them in a _SESSION? Checking the session for every single select item seems too brute force.

**Part 2:** Would fixing this help me out with a library like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920498/trying-to-echo-an-image-source-in-a-select-option-list); to see the dynamic options with images? I believe these two parts are connected.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keep option selected after a refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192640/keep-option-selected-after-a-refresh)

Comment: Already checked that one. Note that I have an empty select object on refresh. Storing the whole options list is a possible way, sure, but surely there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### About Part 1:

The key point is refreshing the page. First let us consider the case what is happening now - you are probably keeping the options selected using `$_POST`. After the selection and reloading is done it shows the response of `POST` action [as your data is being posted into the same page - guessing from your scenario]. Now when somebody reloads the browser the `POST` request becomes empty. So all the selections are lost.

There can be lots of ways/tricks for this.
`$_SESSION` can be one of them / `$_COOKIE` can be one of them / through some `JS` you can use browser local storage, etc.

The main concept will be the fact to keep the values somewhere where a browser refresh doesn't effect. So though `$_SESSION` seems `brut force` to you -- it is a logical option.

### About Part 2:

I think these two parts are **not** connected. As long as you are using regular **`select`** options for showing your options - they are not connected -- as your part two deals with styling your option values not how the work.

Comment: Thank you sir. Will work with sessions and part two is separated indeed. Many thanks.

Comment: @Dave8813, if it works can you please mark it as an answer? Thanks.