# How to add an image to select option in HTML with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to add an image in select option in HTML with PHP.

The image is first fetched from a database.

```
echo '<option value='.$ifet['productimage'].'><img src='.$ifet['productimage'].'/></option>';
```

Comment: I get blank option in select box using <img src=>

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2966006/1501051

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a images in select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Answer (score 2):

images don't work in select infact any type of CSS is not supported in select except line-height  and border you can use jquery:

here is a demo: **http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo**

Comment: Depends on browser. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2966006/4405465) solution for adding SVG-images in FireFox

Answer (score 2):

To add images in a select list you'll have to add them as a background-image.

```
<select>
    <option value='displayvalue' style='background-image:url(".print $ifet['productimage'].");'></option>
</select>
```

or use it as CSS

```
select option[value='displayvalue']
{background-image:url(".print $ifet['productimage'].");}
```

Comment: you can't use php variables in css

Comment: There's still inline CSS :)
As in `<style></style>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<option value="<?=$ifet['productimage']?>"><img src="<?=$ifet['productimage']?>" /></option>
```

OR

```
<option value="<?php echo $ifet['productimage']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $ifet['productimage']; ?>" /></option>
```