# Adding image to a select option

Tags: javascript, html

I am using `document.createElement('option')` in `otion.text`. I need to append image with text.

Below is how I am doing it, without much success:

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect'),
    newOption = document.createElement('option');

newOption.value = 'bmw';

if (typeof newOption.innerText === 'undefined') {
    newOption.textContent = 'BMW' < img src = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash1/t5/27599546049768_1093999943_q.jpg" > ;
} else {
    newOption.innerText = 'BMW' < img src = "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash1/t5/27599546049768_1093999943_q.jpg" > ;
}

mySelect.appendChild(newOption);
```

and my HTML is:

```
<select id="mySelect">

</select>
```

How to add image and text to `newOption.innerText`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't display images in a `<option></option>` you should take a look at a plugin for this; maybe take a look at this: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

Answer (score 1):

As TryingToImprove said you cannot display images inside `<option>` but you also have another problem. You are not putting your strings together correctly. Regardless, this has already been answered SO located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2966006/845059). Hope this helps.