# How to add small image or icon to <select> option?

Tags: html

I want to make a language selector, but I don't know how?
I'm doing this:

```html
<div class="language">
  <select class="language" style="width:100px">
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="Arabic">Arabic</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

But I need to put a small icon (png or gif) beside the english and arabic options.

I've tried it different ways but nothing happened. Please help about
the best way to do it.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a images in select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Comment: @Css Man did the answer below resolve your issue?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

[updated from my previous answer, it was wrong for select elements]

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select) and the references included in the post, no, this cannot be done. However the community agrees (on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)) that this can be done in Firefox using:

[update]

But as you can see in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zilex/1/edit?html,css,output) the code given as the answer in that second link doesn't seem to work, even in Firefox. I have to agree that the solution would be to create your own "dropdownlist" using HTML Elements that are stylable. Here is a **[great post](http://thephuse.com/development/custom-styling-for-select-menus/)** on how to create your own, pretty easy actually.

Comment: Why #gender? I assume you mean #language? Also, perhaps provide a working JSFiddle as I cannot seem to get this code working.

Comment: @Matthew MacLean for clarity I updated my answer, good lookin' out.