# Add icon in select ng-options using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```html
 <select 
    name="" 
    id="packageId" 
    class="form-control" 
    ng-model="client.selectedPackage" 
    ng-options="package as package.pM_Name for package in packages" 
    ng-change="changePackage(client.selectedPackage)" 
    required>
         <option value="">Select a package</option>
</select>
```

I want to add glyphicons on every options 
i tried with class="glyphicons glyphicons-book" but it does not work can any one help me out

thanks in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579390/how-to-add-small-image-or-icon-to-select-option