# Drop down Select with Images in Option in Backbone.js template

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to show images in `Dropdown options` in `Backbone template`. Each option will have image in it. I have tried different ways of doing this but couldn't succeed. Can anyone let me know correct way of doing this.

Here is code i am trying:

```
         <div class="optionWrapper">
            <select id="<%= id %>" class="extra_option">
              <% _.each(options, function (opt) { %>
                <option value="1" <img src="<? echo $uploads;?>option_thumbnails/<%= opt.thumbnail_file %>">></option> 
              <% }); %>                      
            </select>
         </div>
```

Comment: You need to use custom select for this task. With native implementation of select tag it's not a good idea to use `<img>` tag inside of select options. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list) a few workarounds.

Comment: Yes, and one more thing. Your `each` block should be in select tag.

Comment: I think its not possible, as `<option>` only supports text.

Comment: Since i didn't find any solution so what i did is i made **<li>** of option images and put this **<ul>** in Bootstrap **Collapse**. In this way i achieved above drop down functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class="optionWrapper">
            <select id=<%= id %> class="extra_option">
              <% _.each(options, function (opt) { %>
                <option value="1" <img src="<? echo $uploads;?>option_thumbnails/<%= opt.thumbnail_file %>>></option> 
              <% }); %>                      
            </select>
         </div>
```

Try without the doublequote around your template part (<%=id> and <%= opt.thumbnail_file %>)

Comment: No that's not the problem.

Comment: And also around your php code.

<img src=<? echo $uploads;?>+"option_thumbnails/"+<%= opt.thumbnail_file %>>