# The best way to add images in <select> <option>

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

What is actually the best way to add images in `<select> <option>`?
I need to add country flags in my list. I use AngularJS and jQuery.
Cross-browser is important for me. I try `background-image` and few old jquery plugins, but it dosen't works in Chrome.

So how can I add image in list items? Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: can you add what you tried in OP

Comment: `<option>` can only contain text for a reason. The OS is in charge of select popups and usually doesn't allow you to style them much. If you want something fancier, you'll need to build it in Javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

Comment: @AleksanderKolev thank you. The information said it doesn't support again since 2014 :(

Answer (score -1):

I think this plugin will be help you
[jquery-image-dropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)

or

You can do your own follow this article [Icons for Select Menu Options in HTML/CSS](http://binnyva.blogspot.com/2006/01/icons-for-select-menu-options-in.html)

Or

Here is another Demo

```js
            $(".dropdown img.flag").addClass("flagvisibility");

            $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
                $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
            });
                        
            $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
                var text = $(this).html();
                $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
                $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
                $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
            });
                        
            function getSelectedValue(id) {
                return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
            }

            $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
                var $clicked = $(e.target);
                if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
                    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
            });



                $(".dropdown img.flag").toggleClass("flagvisibility");
```

```css
      body { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; font-size:0.75em; color:#000;}
        .desc { color:#6b6b6b;}
        .desc a {color:#0092dd;}
        
        .dropdown dd, .dropdown dt, .dropdown ul { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
        .dropdown dd { position:relative; }
        .dropdown a, .dropdown a:visited { color:#816c5b; text-decoration:none; outline:none;}
        .dropdown a:hover { color:#5d4617;}
        .dropdown dt a:hover { color:#5d4617; border: 1px solid #d0c9af;}
        .dropdown dt a {background:#e4dfcb url('http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/reinventing-drop-down/arrow.png') no-repeat scroll right center; display:block; padding-right:20px;
                        border:1px solid #d4ca9a; width:150px;}
        .dropdown dt a span {cursor:pointer; display:block; padding:5px;}
        .dropdown dd ul { background:#e4dfcb none repeat scroll 0 0; border:1px solid #d4ca9a; color:#C5C0B0; display:none;
                          left:0px; padding:5px 0px; position:absolute; top:2px; width:auto; min-width:170px; list-style:none;}
        .dropdown span.value { display:none;}
        .dropdown dd ul li a { padding:5px; display:block;}
        .dropdown dd ul li a:hover { background-color:#d0c9af;}
        
        .dropdown img.flag { border:none; vertical-align:middle; margin-left:10px; }
        .flagvisibility { display:none;}
```

```html
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
        <dt><a href="#"><span>Please select the country</span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Brazil<img class="flag" src="http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/reinventing-drop-down/br.png" alt="" /><span class="value">BR</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">France<img class="flag" src="http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/reinventing-drop-down/fr.png" alt="" /><span class="value">FR</span></a></li>
               
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: There is not even an image in your example

Answer (score -1):

Consider using [Selectize](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) — a jQuery based library which *transforms* the ordinary select element and lets you embed images and other dynamic functionality.

Answer (score -9):

HTML & CSS together:

```
<select>
  <option style="background-image:url(usa.png);">USA</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(uk.png);">UK</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(france.png);">France</option>
</select>
```

HTML

```
<select id="country">
  <option>USA</option>
  <option>UK</option>
  <option>France</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
select#country option[value="USA"]   { background-image:url(usa.png);   }
select#country option[value="UK"] { background-image:url(uk.png); }
select#country option[value="France"] { background-image:url(france.png); }
```

Comment: you copy-pasted from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list    and you ' forgot ' to edit the CSS part ( you left #gender instead of #country )  . PLUS it only works for Firefox and the OP explicitly said he wants cross-browser .    -1 from me