# Am I able to add an img tag inside the option tag dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is the code

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonArr.length; i++) {
    var obj = jsonArr[i];
    htmlText += '<option value="'+obj.place+'">' + placeName + '</option>';
}
```

I want to show Images as well as place name on the option tag dynamically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list.

Comment: In short: no, you need to use a javascript plugin/ or write your own code that emulates a select box with divs/plain html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from your question, you mentioned as

```
for(var i=0;i<jsonArr.length;i++){
                    var obj = jsonArr[i];
                    htmlText += '<option value="'+obj.place+'">'+placeName+'</option>';
                }
```

this is not possible, you need to use plugins

try this:

```
<option value="vaulue_in_integer" id="ID" style="background: url(imageName.png) right no-repeat; width: ABCpx; height: ABCpx">DEMO_TEXT</option>
```