# How to show up an image when an option is selected in dropdownlist in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on a website i.e a tours and travel website in which I have been stuck at a place where I need to show up an image when a option is selected in drop down list and the image is retrieved from database and the image is stored in binary data and also the data value of drop down  list is retrieved from database so I wanted to display the image as soon as the option is selected in drop down list .Below is the database I have created:

[image: This is the Image of the database from which I want to retrieve image and subcatname in dropdown list]

Form Image:

[image: Image of the form on which i want to retrieve image and subcatname in dropdown list]

Comment: you should check that post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that u are using webforms, 
Follow the Steps :

- Add Eventlistener onDropdownSelectionChanged

### In event Listener -

- Fetch Using id from Database
- Get the ImageButton /    Tag
- Convert to image and save in temp path
- Display By Setting    ImageUrl Property

Comment: can you add a code for me I m new to asp.net so dont know much about all this stuffs ? @steve

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "value 1")
        {
            Image1.ImageUrl = "images/image-1.png";
        }
        else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "value 2")
        {
            Image1.ImageUrl = "images/image-2.png";
        }

        ...
        ...
        ...

        else
        {
          Image1.ImageUrl = "images/image-n.png";
        }
```