# Electronic Logic Gates

Tags: html, css

I want a Drop-Down Menu (Html Select Option) with Content *Countryflag + Country Name*

To lower http requests i want to realize it with 1 image with all flags and display just a part from it.

i use this stripes
https://www.flag-sprites.com/de/

Without html form with option list it works like:

```
<img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-cz" alt="Czech Republic" />
```

but

```
<option><img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-cz" alt="Czech Republic" /> Czech Republic</option>
```

is forbidden

also if i do it like this:

```
<option class="flag flag-cz">Czech Republic</option>
```

it does not give the results i want

Here is an Example how it should looks like:
http://find-onlinecontacts.com

Comment: Why is the title "Electronic Logic Gates" when the question has nothing whatsoever to do with them?

Comment: I'm curious about the title too

Comment: I don't see any flags on the example URL you posted.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach. It's behaviour is the same as a select but you can custumize it easily.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $(".option").click(function() {
    $(".option").slideDown();
  });

  $(".option:not(.selected)").click(function() {
    $(".option:not(.selected)").slideUp();

    $(".option.selected").text($(this).text())
    $("#selectVal").val($(this).data("value"))
  });




});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none
}

.option {
  display: none
}

.option:first-child {
  display: block
}

.option:not(.selected):hover {
  background: red
}

#select {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer
}

#select img{width:30px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="select">
  <li class="option selected">--</li>
  <li class="option" data-value="0"><img src="http://www.flags.net/images/largeflags/SPAN0002.GIF" alt=""/>Spain</li>
  <li class="option" data-value="1"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5c/Flag_of_Portugal.svg/255px-Flag_of_Portugal.svg.png" alt=""/>Portugal</li>
  
</ul>
<input id="selectVal" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use SELECT  tag with Size and name method

Comment: you can't put images on a simple select

Comment: Maybe an emoji of the flag 

Comment: Welcome to SO & thank you for participating in questions. As every answer posted here maybe read  [& learned] by many users, please make sure you really have enough information to answer a particular question. Anyway, as the first one, you can review the [correct answer for this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list#answer-2966006)