# Star rating in Dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like to do a simple star rating in a dropdown on an XPage. There seems to be a problem with the codepage or something similar. In Designer everything looks OK (except that the stars  are b/w in Designer) but I get ?? in the dropdown. If I am doing things TOTALLY incorrectly I do not mind using something else (eg. ExtLib)

[image: Example]

here is the code

```html
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox1" value="#{viewScope.mon_bewertung}"> 
   <xp:selectItem itemLabel=" " itemValue="0"></xp:selectItem>
   <xp:selectItem itemLabel="1 " itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem> 
   <xp:selectItem itemLabel="2 " itemValue="2"></xp:selectItem> 
   <xp:selectItem itemLabel="3 " itemValue="3"></xp:selectItem> 
   <xp:selectItem itemLabel="4 " itemValue="4"></xp:selectItem> 
   <xp:selectItem itemLabel="5 " itemValue="5"></xp:selectItem> 
</xp:comboBox>
```

Thanking you in advance 
Ursus

Comment: A hint may be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list

Comment: Please, add to your question what HTML it renders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `xp:selectItem` it isn't possible to reference an image.

> Item Label ‏(itemLabel) Specifies the **text** displayed for the selection
>   item to the user

You could try to add background images to your `xp:comboBox` selection list as mentioned above:

[How to add a images in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Another option would be to try something similar to the following example:

http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating-demo-theme-fa

```xml
<input id="input-1-ltr-star-xs" name="input-1-ltr-star-xs" class="kv-ltr-theme-fa-star rating-loading" value="1" dir="ltr" data-size="xs">
<br/>
<input id="input-2-ltr-star-sm" name="input-2-ltr-star-sm" class="kv-ltr-theme-fa-star rating-loading" value="2" dir="ltr" data-size="sm">
<br/>
<input id="input-3-ltr-star-md" name="input-3-ltr-star-md" class="kv-ltr-theme-fa-star rating-loading" value="3" dir="ltr" data-size="md">
<br/>
<input id="input-4-ltr-star-lg" name="input-4-ltr-star-lg" class="kv-ltr-theme-fa-star rating-loading" value="4" dir="ltr" data-size="lg">
<br/>
<input id="input-5-ltr-star-xl" name="input-5-ltr-star-xl" class="kv-ltr-theme-fa-star rating-loading" value="5" dir="ltr" data-size="xl">
<br/>

<script>
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $('.kv-ltr-theme-fa-star').rating({
        hoverOnClear: false,
        theme: 'krajee-fa'
    });
});
</script>
```

For implementing the above example you could use e.g. xpages `xp:inputText` core controls...