# Displaying images on a select tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select tag with nested option tags. I want to use this to display images, however the images are not displaying. Am I not understanding how the select tag works?

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="image-picker masonry" id="image_picker" style="width: 10000px; height: 10000px;">
        <option class="masonryitem brick" img src="/Images/Image1.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="">
        </option>

        <option class="masonryitem brick" img src="/Images/Image2.jpg" width="180" height="270" alt="" >
        </option>
    </select>
```

I want to make the images use the `image-picker` so they can be selectable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a images in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Comment: You cant do that. This question has been asked many times before. Also, your HTML not valid.

Comment: I do not want to create a drop down list with images. I want  to create a gallery. Something like this https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

Comment: So are you having a problem with that specific plugin? Or are you wanting to do this yourself from scratch? In which case your question would be far too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="image-picker masonry" id="image_picker" style="width: 10000px; height: 10000px;">
        <option class="masonryitem brick" alt="">one
        </option>
        <option class="masonryitem brick"  alt="" >two
        </option>
    </select>
```

**CSS**

```
select#image_picker option[value="one"]   { background-image:url(/Images/Image1.jpg);   }
select#image_picker option[value="two"] { background-image:url(/Images/Image2.jpg); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation clearly states:

> Simply add the attribute data-img-src with the url of the image you want to use as a preview