# background is not working inside select input field on google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add icon inside `select input` tag its working in `Firefox` but not working in `Google Chrome` anybody can solve it? My code is below what is have tried.

```css
select{ font-size:18px;}
.bride{ background:url('https://www.shareicon.net/data/32x32/2016/04/06/745724_people_512x512.png') top right no-repeat; float:right;}
.groom{ background:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-male-avatars/32/Male-Avatar-Cool-Sunglasses-icon.png') top right no-repeat; float:right;}
```

```html
<select>
<option value="Female" class="bride">Bride</option>
<option value="Male" class="groom">Groom</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a images in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you https://jsfiddle.net/7x1v5wyy/1/

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
myFunction = function() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}

.dropdown-content a  img {
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Select Gender</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/32x32/2016/04/06/745724_people_512x512.png" /> Male</a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/free-male-avatars/32/Male-Avatar-Cool-Sunglasses-icon.png" /> Female</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.