# Can't add flag image to <option>

Tags: html, css

I cant add flag image to option, in any ways (html,css)!

```
<select>
    <option value="rus" selected>Rus</option>
    <option value="Uzb" >Uzb</option>
    <option value="eng">Eng</option>
</select>
```

Comment: By all appearances, you haven't tried.

Comment: Where's the css?

Comment: Please read [**How to ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a images in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Comment: what are you looking for help or code..?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the flag image in `Style`. Like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="rus" style="background-image:url(rus.png);">Rus</option>
  <option value="Uzb" style="background-image:url(uzb.png);">Uzb</option>
  <option value="eng" style="background-image:url(eng.png);">Eng</option>
</select>
```

You need the flag images also. And call this in Like: `background-image(yor_flag_image_link)`.