# Django adding img to the <option>

Tags: python, django, html

Hello i got a question to u guys. How can i add a specific img to each of this options in django

```
    <select id="sTypes2" name="current_tier" class="form-control input-lg c-square">
        <option value="Silver I">Silver I</option>
        <option value="Silver II">Silver II</option>
        <option value="Silver III">Silver III</option>
        <option value="Silver IV">Silver IV</option>
        <option value="Silver Elite">Silver Elite</option>
        <option value="Silver Elite Master">Silver Elite Master</option>
        <option value="Gold Nova I">Gold Nova I</option>
        <option value="Gold Nova II">Gold Nova II</option>
        <option value="Gold Nova III">Gold Nova III</option>
        <option value="Gold Nova Master">Gold Nova Master</option>
        <option value="Master Guardian I">Master Guardian I</option>
        <option value="Master Guardian II">Master Guardian II</option>
        <option value="Master Guardian Elite">Master Guardian Elite</option>
        <option value="Distinguished Master Guardian">Distinguished Master Guardian</option>
        <option value="Legendary Eagle">Legendary Eagle</option>
        <option value="Legendary Eagle Master">Legendary Eagle Master</option>
        <option value="Supreme Master First Class">Supreme Master First Class</option>
        <option value="Global Elite">Global Elite</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like Django question. It is a bit of HTML. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Comment: I'm new to the django and at first i created the frontend to site now i'm converting it to django templates etc. and my question is should i create a model for for the images for each option? Just a example what i'm trying to do. [link](https://imbaboost.com/rank-boost.html)