# How do I add child elements to a SelectOption?

Tags: java, apache, wicket

How do I add child elements to a org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.select.SelectOption

I have tried the following:

```
SelectOption<String> wicketSelectOption = new SelectOption<String>("option", new Model<>(selectOption.getValue()));
wicketSelectOption.setRenderBodyOnly(false);
wicketSelectOption.setEscapeModelStrings(false);


Label label = new Label("optionLabel", "<i class=\"icon\"></i>" + selectOption.getLabel());
label.setEscapeModelStrings(false);

wicketSelectOption.add(label);
```

**Result:**

The < i > tag is completely ignored

Comment: What are you trying to archieve here? A `SelectOption` belongs to an `<option>` tag and that one isn't allowed to have anything but simple text as content (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option). If you want to have a DropDown with images/icons you either need to use something different than a simple select or try to archieve it with styling: [How to add a images in select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS displaying an icon for each option

Comment: Check out DropDownChoice, maybe it will help you. It could have a list of choices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `optionLabel` as a child in the markup:

```
<option wicket:id="option">
    <wicket:container wicket:id="optionLabel"/>
</option>
```

I would suggest to use something like:

```
<option wicket:id="option">
    <i wicket:id="optionIcon"/> <wicket:container wicket:id="optionLabel"/>
</option>
```

This way you have full control.