# Put Image in dropdownlist programatically ASP

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

In code behind I am creating a Control : a dropdownlist with inside some pictures.

```
DropDownList ddlEventIcone = new DropDownList();
ddlEventIcone.ID = "eventIconeDDL";
ddlEventIcone.Width = Unit.Pixel(110);
```

Then I want to put picutures inside, so I get them from a map created like so :

```
Dictionary<string, Image> iconeMapping = new Dictionary<string, Image>();
iconeMapping .Add(iconeName, myImage);
```

I put them in a ListItem which I'll bind to the dropdownlist:

```
foreach (Image image in iconeMapping.Values.ToArray())
{
    lImageddl.Add(image.ImageUrl.Replace("~", "../.."));// the tild wasn't working
}
```

I bind my list with the dropdownList :

```
ddlEventIcone .DataSource = lImageddl;
ddlEventIcone .DataBind();
```

I use Javascript to precise the 'type' of the element as Img:

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in ddlEventIcone.Items.Cast<ListItem>())
{
   listItem.Attributes.Add("class", "imageconverter");
 }
```

With the Javascript :

```
  $(function () {
            $(".imageconverter").each(function () {
                $(this).html('<img src="' + $(this).text() + '">');
            });
        });
```

The Result is a dropdownlist with 'empty' options, nothing is shown (blank rows) BUT in the source page here is what I've got :

```
<select name="DigitalCalendarGrid$ctl09$eventIconeDDL" id="DigitalCalendarGrid_ctl09_eventIconeDDL" style="width:110px;">
        <option value="../../images/Event/cycling.png" class="imageconverter" width="10" height="10"><img src="../../images/Event/cycling.png"></option>
        <option value="../../images/Event/football.png" class="imageconverter" width="10" height="10"><img src="../../images/Event/football.png"></option>
    </select>
```

EDIT Precision : in the Chrome DevTools when I pass the mouse on the picture path it shows the picture but it says

```
0x0 pixels (Natural 256x256 pixels)
```

Comment: possible duplicate -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list

Comment: As rfar as i know, you cant use image tag inside a select option. Its better to use some javascript library like: http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick , http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render , https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

Comment: Seems like it is not possible unless using external librairy... Too bad....