# color boxes inside select option html

Tags: javascript, html, css

color boxes inside select option in html 
i want do it using html and css and without using jquery or javascript
[Output should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcR7s.png)

i have tried

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#"><span style="background-color:Red">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    Red</a>
    <a href="#"> <span style="background-color:Green">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> Green
    </a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <span class="color" style="background-color:Red">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> Red
    <span class="color" style="background-color:Green">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> Green
  </div>
</div>
```

but output should display color boxes inside dropdown.
color boxes inside select option html

here i am using anchor tag and div tag in the code i have written.
but i want it in select, option tag

Comment: i converted the code you posted to a snippet and it basically looks like the image you posted.  can you please clarify what you want it to do that it's not already doing?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NjaEL/59/
this is the example i have refered...but there they used jqery 
i want it with html and css without adding js and jqury

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without JavaScript - here's some very simple click handlers that do what you want:

```js
function updateColor(element) {
    var newColor = element.firstChild.style.backgroundColor;
    element.parentElement.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
    console.log(newColor);
}
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<h2>Dropdown Menu</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" onclick="updateColor(this)"><span style="background-color:Red" onclick="updateColor(this)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    Red</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="updateColor(this)"><span style="background-color:Green">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> Green
    </a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div onclick="updateColor(this)"><span class="color" style="background-color:Red">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> Red</div>
    <div onclick="updateColor(this)"><span class="color" style="background-color:Green" onclick="updateColor(this)">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> Green</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list
i referred this also...here they did it with images...but i want it color box

Answer (score 0):

Remove "min-width: 160px;" from .dropdown-content

And

Remove "padding: 12px 16px;" from .dropdown-content a

Comment: i am unable to select particular color(option)...can you see output image..