# How to display country flags on waffle chart symbols? (using, e.g,. `ggwaffle`)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, charts, waffle-chart

I would like to create a waffle chart and use country flags in place of squares. Here is my current attempt using [`ggwaffle`](https://liamgilbey.github.io/ggwaffle/):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(emojifont)
library(ggwaffle)

iris2 <- iris
iris2$Species <- c("", "", "")

waffle_data <- waffle_iron(iris2, aes_d(group = Species))
waffle_data$label = fontawesome('fa-flag')

ggplot(waffle_data, aes(x, y, colour = group)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=label), family='fontawesome-webfont', size=7) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_colour_waffle() +
  theme_waffle()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Is it possible at all with `ggwaffle`? I was also trying to play with [`ggflags`](https://github.com/jimjam-slam/ggflags) but I don't see how to make these two compatible because `ggflags` replace points in a scatter plot.

I am also aware that Windows does not ship with country flag unicode emojis for [political reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62729729/how-do-i-view-country-flags-on-windows-10-through-html), so base unicode wouldn't work (as in one of my previous attempts using the [`waffle`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle) package). So it would need to be a font that includes country flags or images thereof. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ggflags you could set the x and y coordinates to replicate a grid.

```r
library(ggflags)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(x=rep(1:15, each = 10),
                  y=rep(1:10, 15),
                  country = c(rep("us", 75), rep("ca", 50), rep("gb", 25)))

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y, country=country)) + 
  geom_flag() +
  scale_country() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Here's a go at a function which can automate this, it's more than a bit hacky but may be useful as a starter...

````r
library(ggflags)
library(ggplot2)



``` r
#' @param in_map_var string Vector of elements to be mapped to flags
#' @param len_x integer Length of x axis, number of flags on x axis
#' @param na_flag string ID of a flag which is nominally used for filling in the empty grid spaces, This is a hack.

waffle_map <- function(in_map_var, len_x = NA, na_flag = "ac"){

  # work out grid dimensions  
  var_count <- length(in_map_var)
  
  if(is.na(len_x)){
    x_count <- ceiling(sqrt(var_count))
  } else {
    x_count <- len_x
  }

  
  y_count <- ceiling(var_count / x_count)
  grid_count <- x_count * y_count
  
  df <- 
    data.frame(x = rep(1:y_count, each = x_count),
               y = rep(1:x_count, y_count),
               country = c(in_map_var, rep(na_flag, grid_count - var_count))
               )

  country_4legend <- unique(df$country)[unique(df$country) != na_flag]
  
  
  
  p <- 
    ggplot(df, aes(x, y, country = country)) + 
    geom_flag(size = 8) +
    scale_country(breaks = country_4legend) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")

    if(grid_count > var_count){
    p <- 
      p +
      geom_point(data = df[var_count:grid_count, ], aes(x, y), colour = "white", size = 10)
  }
                 
  return(p)
  
}

var_2map <- c(rep("us", 75), rep("ca", 50), rep("gb", 25))

waffle_map(var_2map, len_x = 15)
````

[image]

```r
waffle_map(var_2map)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Very nice and straightforward. But how to add the legend back for the country names? I tried `show.legend = TRUE` and it does not change anything :/

Comment: It would be cool if we could find a way to convert the original data to this sort of x and y coordinates data automatically since in my use case it is a dynamic table that updates automatically based on new data every week so I could not do it manually every time. Will try to think of something.

Comment: Updated to include a legend. I'll have a think about a function to generate an x, y coordinates grid.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for editing your answer! I had tried `theme(legend.position = "right")` but was missing the `scale_country()` bit before. Cool stuff 

Comment: For future readers, note that although the `scale_country()` function is used in the `ggflags` package README, it is not documented: `> ?ggflags::scale_country
No documentation for ‘scale_country’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??scale_country’`

Comment: Have provided a rather hacky function to manage automatic generation of a grid. Not tested this for any other cases apart from the two cases illustrated. Hopefully it provides a starter for 10.

Comment: That's pretty amazing! You could probably submit a PR to ggflags with this... Only thing is that to make it a regular waffle we would also need an `len_y` argument to make it a 10x10 square so that each flag = 1% of the data.

Comment: Here's a way to modify the data set within the function for this purpose: `library(dplyr)

var_2map <- c(rep("us", 75), rep("ca", 50), rep("gb", 25))
length(var_2map)
#> [1] 150

var_2map <- data.frame(country = var_2map)

my_prop <- var_2map %>% 
  count(country) %>% 
  mutate(n2 = round(n/nrow(var_2map) * 100))
my_prop
#>   country  n n2
#> 1      ca 50 33
#> 2      gb 25 17
#> 3      us 75 50

var_2map2 <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(my_prop)), \(x) {
  rep(my_prop$country[x], my_prop$n2[x])}) %>% 
  unlist

length(var_2map2)
#> [1] 100`

Comment: I have promoted your great answer on Twitter: https://twitter.com/RemPsyc/status/1673444697715494913