# HTML symbol not displaying in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, unicode

I want to display the following symbol : `"\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8"`
This, in HTML, is supposed to display the flag of the USA. The first half displays "U", and the 2nd half displays "S". Put together, it displays a little symbol of the flag (by a mechanism I'm not sure about). Well, it does in Firefox at least. It doesn't in Chrome. In Chrome, it just shows "U S".

I wish Chrome could work as well as Firefox :D
But stats tell us a large proportion of Internet users use Chrome.

Any idea what I am missing so Chrome displays the flag symbol ?
I initially had this in the index.html head :

`<meta charset=utf-8">`

Another SO comment mentionned it had to be replaced with the following, but that doesn't fix the issue.

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

EDIT : [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519758/flag-emojis-not-rendering/54663926) indicates there is no fix. The way would be to use images (.png/.webp/.svg) instead. This is a bit dumb. I feel like the unicode solution would be the lightest.

Comment: Note: your question lacks of fundamental details: where you put the symbol `"\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8"`? It is important to know the context (and your linked solution use entities, so it is also not applicable here. (and yeah: `select/option` tags are badly defined in HTML. it is a well known problem).

Comment: as follows : <p>{"\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8"}</p>. Or the following HTML equivalent : <p>&#127482;&#127480;</p>. In both cases, Firefox displays the flag, while Chrome displays letters U and S

Answer (score 1):

> [...] `"\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8"` This, in HTML, is supposed to display the flag of the USA.

No `"\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8"` in HTML is supposed to read `"\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8"`.
HTML uses [HTML entities](http://HTML%20entities), the ones for this glyph are `&#x1F1FA;&#x1F1F8;`.

```html
&#x1F1FA; + &#x1F1F8; = &#x1F1FA;&#x1F1F8;
```

Comment: Well, my code speaks for itself. The code mentioned does display the flag as expected. Again, in Firefox, not in Chrome.

Comment: Then your code is not HTML. https://jsfiddle.net/y5b3dcvo/ run this fiddle in any browser you'll have `"\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8"`

Comment: ... The string `"\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8"` when parsed as HTML will generate a TextNode whose value will be `"\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8"`. That's how HTML works. If you have something else, then your sequence hasn't been parsed by an HTML parser. If this happens it's because your code is not HTML. `elem.innerHTML = "\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8";` is JavaScript, not HTML, the sequence is parsed by the JS engine. For HTML what you need is HTML entities.