# How to add images or arrows next to options on dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So how do I add arrows or images next to options on a dropdown list WITHOUT the use of stuff like Select2 or Jquery? Basically, I want to do this:

[image]

I've searched already but everyone is saying I'd need Jquery and stuff which I don't want to use.

Comment: Well... It's a complex task. This is why everybody is saying that you should say something ready-made. You can't personalize <option> with CSS so there's no easy way to do that.

Comment: Look at that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list

Comment: there's no simple, foolproof, cross-browser way to do it. This is one reason why things like select2 exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)