# how to put image in dropdown rows in php

Tags: php, html-select

I am trying to put countries flag infront of there respective country code likein gmail registration something like this:

[image]

I tried with `img src` and `background` but images are not visible.I have a table in mysql with ISO,country name,code. I am trying to use `https://ipdata.co/flags` api to populate flag. 
My code:

```
<select Emp Name='NEW'>
        <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
                 <?
            $list=mysqli_query($con,"select * from country");
        while($row_list=mysqli_fetch_assoc($list)){
            $display="+".$row_list['phonecode']."-".$row_list['name'];
            $flag=$row_list['isosmall'];
            ?>
            <option style="background-image:url(https://ipdata.co/flags/<?php echo $flag;?>.png);"></option>
               // <option value="<img src="https://ipdata.co/flags/<?php echo $flag;?>.png"/></option>
               // <? echo $display; ?>"</option><? if($row_list['iso']==$select){ echo "selected"; } ?>
                                    // <?//echo $row_list['name'];
                                     //echo $display;?>
                </option>
            <?
            }
               ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: Just as a matter of best practices, you really shouldn't put your query inside your HTML like that.

Also, are you getting anything back or is it just the flags missing?

Comment: I am getting blank dropdown, as I am just populating flags. If I echo `$display` it shows code and country like `+91-India`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

Comment: are you sure that  $flag contains what value you are expecting. and i found one bug that you have forggoten to commet </option> at the last section

Comment: What about jquery plugin ?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava yes possibly but it doesnt tells me how to use img scr or URL as image

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm thanks for pointing, fixed but still same

Comment: @mark i'm asking you "what about jquery plugin" .. 
Have you ever thought of using a jquery plugin?

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm could you point me to an example ? how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [this](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/#IconsandImages) jquery plugin and replace with your data:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.8.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.8.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select class="country" name="wcpbc-manual-country" id="country">
        <option value="AU" data-iconurl="https://aus.merchnow.com/img/location-aus.png">AU some text</option>
        <option value="IN" data-iconurl="https://images0.voylla.com/flags/inr.gif">IN some text</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
 $("#country").selectBoxIt();
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/4c1z2oyu/)

Comment: how do I put my URL in `<option value="AU" data-iconurl="https://aus.merchnow.com/img/location-aus.png">AU some text</option>` like this `<option value="AU" data-iconurl="https://ipdata.co/flags/<?php echo $flag;?>.png">AU some text</option>`

Comment: I tried `<?php $flag='us'; ?>
        <option value="AU" data-iconurl="https://ipdata.co/flags/<?php $flag;?>.png">AU some text</option>` But flag disappeared

Comment: Are you sure, that `https://ipdata.co/flags/<?php $flag;?>.png` this is  the correct path ? Can you echo it and post it in browser to check ?

Comment: this is the URL `https://ipdata.co/flags/us.png` I need to replace `us` with my table's value

Comment: Okay, then are you sure, that `$flag` contains `us` ? also check console for any errors ?

Comment: this is strange i put `<?php $flag="us"; echo $flag; ?>` just below `<body>` tag and its not showing any value

Comment: Try with `<?php $flag="us"; echo $flag; exit;?>`

Comment: No, same result, is it because in fiddle it is HTML ?

Comment: Man .. Fiddle was only for example you can do these checks in your script :)

Comment: Thank you it worked. Silly mistakes like missed `</select>` .Thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear it !