# How to display image in dropdown select jQuery using Select2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to display an image inside the dropdown select using Select2 library but the image is not appear. I have refer link below as reference also tried both code below but not solve.

The expectation as below:

[image]

Reference: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

```
$('#preSvcSink').append($("<option selected style='background-image:url('img/icon/active.png');'></option>").attr("value", id).text(new_status));

$('#preSvcSink').append($("<option selected);'></option>").attr("value", id).text(new_status).html('<img src="img/icon/active.png">'));
```

Comment: Can you please show us the html code you are using?

Comment: Please check this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list`

Comment: @RaviAshara that's not relevant here as the OP claims to be using Select2